Resolving basemap fit and pixel size challenges in SMAP L3 Radiometer Global Daily 36 km EASE-Grid Soil Moisture
How can I ensure that the SMAP L3 Radiometer Global Daily 36 km EASE-Grid Soil Moisture Version 6 raster data aligns correctly with the basemap, considering that the raster image is not fitting properly and the pixel size is too large?
What steps can be taken to rectify these issues and achieve accurate alignment and visualization of the raster data with the basemap?


The documentation suggests the correct projection is EPSG:6933
https://nsidc.org/data/spl3smp/versions/6
